# Python with Outllok win32.client question

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

i am trying to access the "recipient" outlook object in python 3.9 using win32.clients import, but can only access "recipients". Recipients does not have an "address" property, but "recipient" does to get the recipients email address from an outbox as desired. anyone have a work around or other recommended libraries to accomplish this? the recipient object exists, i just cant access it learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient

```
    import win32com.client as win32
    import os
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
    messageobjectlist = []
    reciplist = []
    messages = outbox.Items
    received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
    messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
    for each in messages:
        if each.Class == 43:
            messageobjectlist.append(each)
    for x in messageobjectlist:
           reciplist.append(x.Recipients) #this is the problem, if i try to grab addresses from this, "recipients" does not have the property, only "recipient" does, but python tells me "recipient" is unknown
           print(x)
    for y in reciplist:
        print(y)
#this is the output from the code above, unknown coms instead of desired addresses
back up code
RE: Group Kickoff
RE: Thank You
RE: spac-research_1652212493196.csv
Outlook Programmatic Permissions
RE:  (cmts 5.10.22)
RE:  - Fully Executed LOE
RE:  - Fully Executed LOE
RE:  - Fully Executed LOE
FW: logo
RE: Expense report
RE: Expenses - Moving & November Visit 
FW: Thank You
RE: - Advisory (May 2022) (cmts 5.10.22)
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
<COMObject <unknown>>
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: thanks, to be clear, the above code does work, but when i slot in x.recipient.address for x.recipients, doesnt work, says recipient is unknown, when i know for a fact it exists based on this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient

Comment: Your traceback error doesn't reflect the code you posted.  Can you also print out what ```x``` is?

Comment: thanks it is now consistent, there is no error, it just gives me comobject unknown for recipients, and i cant access their addresses, which is the objective. its giving me the email subjects just fine

Comment: so in this case, x is the message object